# ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE in hyperledger fabric in case of private data

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are working a project in which we are using the latest private data collection.
We are running the peers in a kubernetes setup. We have a collection config as described below,

```
 {
    "name": "Org1_PDC2",
    "policy": "OR ('Org1.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 2,
    "memberOnlyRead": true,
    "memberOnlyWrite": true,
    "blockToLive": 0,
    "endorsementPolicy": {
       "signaturePolicy": "OR('Org1.member')"
     }
  }
```

we have 2 organisation in the channel with 2 peers each. Since we have already mentioned the endorsementPolicy for "Org1_PDC2" only needs signature from Org1. but we see that the transaction is also send to the peer1 of Org2. But it fails in org2 since it cannot access  "Org1_PDC2". We also observe that from  nodejs application that when we submit the transaction it gives us an endorsementPolicy Failure and I could see in the peer1 logs of Org1 that the chaincode is executed successfully but in the peer2 of Org1 logs i see the error as

```
2020-11-02 13:18:24.249 UTC [gossip.privdata] fetchPrivateData -> DEBU 566a286 Total members that fit some digest: []
2020-11-02 13:18:24.249 UTC [gossip.privdata] fetchPrivateData -> WARN 566a287 Do not know any peer in the channel( mychannel ) that matches the policies , aborting
2020-11-02 13:18:24.249 UTC [gossip.privdata] populateFromRemotePeers -> WARN 566a288 Failed fetching private data from remote peers for dig2src:



2020-11-02 13:18:25.249 UTC [gossip.privdata] RetrievePvtdata -> DEBU 566a28b Could not fetch all missing collection private write sets from remote peers for block [291588] channel=mychannel
2020-11-02 13:18:25.249 UTC [gossip.privdata] prepareBlockPvtdata -> WARN 566a28c Could not fetch all missing eligible collection private write sets for block [291588]. Will commit block with missing private write sets:[txID: 6d14a881ecc6b437f553fc5df7f8fd29d10d92f22f752a2488fc382d535b62e8, seq: 0, namespace: mycc, collection: Org1_PDC2, hash: b8317508d3b677563bb5119626eabfc866ad561358e2d1a7116749d86c952ebe
] channel=mychannel
```

We are using the discovery option in the nodejs application with option as

```
await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, {discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false}});
const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
const contract = await network.getContract(contractName);
```

and in the connection Profile of org1 client we only kept the information of the peers from org1 and orderer. The error message we get when we invoke any transaction from the client is

```
[TransactionEventHandler]: strategyFail: commit failure for transaction "e7080f63ff9be02002d2723b7431b1e9f236c8119c7c37e7dd21bf924a8a5b7a": TransactionError: Commit of transaction e7080f63ff9be02002d2723b7431b1e9f236c8119c7c37e7dd21bf924a8a5b7a failed on peer peer1.org1.svc.cluster.local with status ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to let the client SDK know about the collections accessed by the chaincode using `contract.addDiscoveryInterest()` before using that Contract to invoke transactions, as described in this tutorial page:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-discovery-fabric-network.html

If that isn't successful then you can explicitly set the organizations used for endorsement with `transaction.setEndorsingOrganizations()`:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Transaction.html#setEndorsingOrganizations